# Parboiled - how to parse a real number?

Tags: scala, parboiled

I took this from a project that claims to parse real numbers, but it somehow eats the pre-decimal part:

```
object Main extends App {
  import org.parboiled.scala._

  val res = TestParser.parseDouble("2.3")
  println(s"RESULT: ${res.result}")

  object TestParser extends Parser {
    def RealNumber = rule { 
      oneOrMore(Digit) ~ optional( "." ~ oneOrMore(Digit) ) ~> { s =>
        println(s"CAPTURED '$s'")
        s.toDouble
      }
    }
    def Digit = rule { "0" - "9" }

    def parseDouble(input: String): ParsingResult[Double] =
      ReportingParseRunner(RealNumber).run(input)
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
CAPTURED '.3'
RESULT: Some(0.3)
```

What is wrong here? Note that currently I cannot go from Parboiled-1 to Parboiled-2, because I have a larger grammar that would have to be rewritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [parboiled documentation](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/wiki/Parser-Actions-in-Scala#the-action-operators), action rules like `~>` take the match of the *immediately preceding peer rule*. In the rule sequence `oneOrMore(Digit) ~ optional( "." ~ oneOrMore(Digit) )` the immediately preceding rule is `optional( "." ~ oneOrMore(Digit) )`, so you get only its match `".3"` in the action rule.

To fix that you may, for example, extract the first two elements into a separate rule:

```
def RealNumberString = rule { 
  oneOrMore(Digit) ~ optional( "." ~ oneOrMore(Digit) ) 
}

def RealNumber = rule {
  RealNumberString ~> { s =>
    println(s"CAPTURED '$s'")
    s.toDouble
  }
}
```

Or push both parts onto the stack and then combine them:

```
def RealNumber = rule {
  oneOrMore(Digit) ~> identity ~ 
  optional( "." ~ oneOrMore(Digit) ) ~> identity ~~> { (s1, s2) =>
    val s = s1 + s2
    println(s"CAPTURED '$s'")
    s.toDouble
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution, but it looks very ugly. Probably there is a better way:

```
def Decimal = rule {
  Integer ~ optional[Int]("." ~ PosInteger) ~~> { (a: Int, bOpt: Option[Int]) =>
    bOpt.fold(a.toDouble)(b => s"$a.$b".toDouble) /* ??? */
}}
def PosInteger  = rule { Digits ~> (_.toInt) }
def Integer     = rule { optional[Unit]("-" ~> (_ => ())) /* ??? */ ~
  PosInteger ~~> { (neg: Option[Unit], num: Int) =>
    if (neg.isDefined) -num else num
  }
}
def Digit       = rule { "0" - "9" }
def Digits      = rule { oneOrMore(Digit) }

def parseDouble(input: String): ParsingResult[Double] =
  ReportingParseRunner(Decimal).run(input)
```